# Probability of Random Variable Question | Probability Error

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I had this question in my past paper:

> Bags of sugar are packed in boxes, each box containing 20 bags. The masses of the boxes, when
> empty, are normally distributed with mean 0.4 kg and standard deviation 0.01 kg. The masses of the
> bags are normally distributed with mean 1.02 kg and standard deviation 0.03 kg.
>
> i) Two full boxes are chosen at random. Find the probability that they differ in mass by less than 0.02 kg

I did the calculations and I got my probability as 2 x 0.4582 however in the marking scheme they've deducted the final answer from 1. Why is that so?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you edit into your question how you got to $2 \times 0.4582$?  My guess is that you doubled the probability that the first box was more than $0.02$kg bigger than the second box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how you arrived at your result but I would do in the following manner:

Set X= boxes' mass and Y=bags' mass.

The gross mass is

$$Z=(X+Y_1+Y_2+\dots +Y_{20})\sim N(20.8;0.0181)$$

and

$$W=(Z_1-Z_2)\sim N(0;0.0362)$$

you are requested to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[|W|<0.02]=\mathbb{P}[-0.02<W<0.02]=$$

$$=\Phi\left(\frac{0.02}{\sqrt{0.0362}}  \right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-0.02}{\sqrt{0.0362}}  \right)=0.5419-0.4581=0.0837$$

Comment: do you know what is the reasoning behind taking -0.02 < w < 0.02? and not just 0.02?

Comment: @Henry : silly me... :(

Answer (score 0):

What you did is probably:

- Variance of the weight of a full box is $0.01^2+20\times 0.03^2=0.0181$
- Variance of the difference between two full boxes is $2\times 0.0181=0.0362$  (and mean is $0$)
- Probability first full box was more than $0.02$kg bigger than the second full box is probability standard normal exceeds $\frac{0.02}{\sqrt{0.0362}}\approx 0.1051177$ which is about $0.4582$
- Probability either box is **more** than $0.02$kg bigger than the other is double that, about $0.9163$

and what you needed to do was the next step

- Probability that they differ in mass by **less** than $0.02$kg is $1$ minus that, about $0.0837$